# check number of multiples of the element in array having index smaller than that element

Tags: c++, algorithm

Problem description:

> You are given a sequence `A1,A2,…,AN`. For each valid `i`, the star value of the element `A_i` is the number of valid indices `j<i` such that `A_j` is divisible by `A_i`. Find the maximum star value in the given sequence.

My attempt:
I have already tried an approach in which I find the max element in array till the `i`'th index (say `MAX_i`). I am keeping a count array `f[]` for all elements. 
I am iterating over from `A_i` to `MAX_i` and in multiples of `A_i` and counting number of elements divisible by `A_i` by 
`ans=ans+f[element]`

```
  long long int n,key,m=-1,ans=0,star_max=-1;
  int f[1000004];
  memset(f, 0, sizeof(f));
  scanf("%lld", &n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
      scanf("%lld", &key);
      ans=0;
      for(long long int i=key;i<m;i+=key)
      {
          ans+=f[i];
      }
      if(ans > star_max)
        star_max=ans;
      f[key]++;
      if (a[i] > m)
        m=a[i];
  }
  cout<<star_max;
```

any O(N) or O(NlogN) approach is appreciated.

Comment: Is it a C++ program or a C program?

Comment: Suppose list is [a,b,c,d,e,f,g].Now if ''d' is divisible by 'g', than all the number behind 'd' which are multiple of 'd' will also be divisible by 'g'. So its obvious that 'g' will have more multiple than 'd'. So, neglect 'd' and no need to check for it.

Comment: @Anubhaw Choudhary May the divisible numbers have a gap between them that is for example A0 is divisible by A3, A1 is not divisible by A3 and A2 is divisible by A3. SO the max length of the divisible numbers is equal to 2. Is it correct?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow yes there can be gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  long long int N;
  long long int c[1000006],val,max_star=-1;
  memset(c, 0, sizeof(c));
  scanf("%lld", &N);
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
      scanf("%lld", &val);
      if(c[val] > max_star)
        max_star=c[val];
      long long int s=sqrt(val);
      for(int j=1;j<=s;j++)
      {
          if(val%j == 0)
          {
              c[j]++;
              long long int r=val/j;
              if(r != j)
              {
                  c[r]++;
              }
          }
      }
  }
    printf("%lld",max_star);
```